# How to parse same name tag in Android XML DOM Parsing?

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing, android-xml

I am not able to parse my XML here. It returns "Item" only.
My `AndroidActivity` cannot be shown as it is very big. That's why I have only shown the part which is responsible for parsing.

My XML Looks like this :

```
<MyResource>
<Item>First</Item>
<Item>Second</Item>
</MyResource>
```

My ActivityClass method:

```
public class ShowItems extends Activity{
    ListView lv;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    static final String KEY_RESOURCE = "MyResource"; // parent node 
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "Item";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String[] from={KEY_ITEM };
    int[] to={R.id.mylist_item};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showitems);
        
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
        parseXML();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist,R.layout.list_item,from , to); 
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

private void parseXML() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    
    final String URL="http://10.0.2.2:8080/MySite/xml";
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); 
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_RESOURCE); 
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i); 
        map.put(KEY_ITEM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM)); 
        mylist.add(map); }
}
```

My XML Parser Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import android.util.Log;
public class XMLParser {
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) { 
        String xml = null; 
        try { 
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        return xml; 
    }
    
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){ 
        Document doc = null; 
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
        try { 
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
            InputSource is = new InputSource(); 
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml)); 
                doc = db.parse(is);  
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { 
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage()); 
                return null; 
            } catch (SAXException e) { 
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage()); 
                return null; 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage()); 
                return null; 
            } 
                // return DOM 
            return doc; 
    }
    
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);         
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0)); 
    } 
    public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) { 
             Node child; 
             if( elem != null){ 
                 if (elem.hasChildNodes()){ 
                     for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){ 
                         if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){ 
                             return child.getNodeValue(); 
                         } 
                     } 
                 } 
             } 
             return ""; 
      } 
}
```

I am not able to parse my XML here. What is the problem here?
It returns "Item" only.
What do I need to do in my `ActivityClass` especially in this part of the code?

```
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); 
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_RESOURCE); 
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        
        
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i); 
        map.put(KEY_ITEM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM)); 
        mylist.add(map); }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want here, can you please be more clear?

Comment: you see his XML. He has two `<Item>` tags that he need to parse through DOM. And When he parse it through the above described method only the first `<Item>` tag is parsed the other (or the reamaining ones) are ignored.

Comment: @AltairRules: 1) Are you getting "First" (or) "Second" as input? 2) Could you print and see size of NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_RESOURCE);?

Comment: I mean "Second" as output, not input

Comment: i am getting output as "Item" when i do this :
`System.out.println(mylist);`

Comment: @AltairRules: What is size of nodeList?

Comment: i can guess that by the previous o/p of `System.out.println(mylist);` as one and that will be "Item" !!
i noticed your answer and i find it very much much close to what i expected :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132776/iterating-a-nodelist-consisting-some-tags-with-same-name-using-dom

Comment: What about try dom4j?

Comment: hmmm...but cant i modify this code and parse the XML....as you can see i have used this parser in other classes too...i think i need to iterate through the list as i have seen somewhere but how to do it is still unknown to me !!

Comment: @Nambari i am getting only `First` as parsed output and "Item" as output of this :`System.out.println(mylist); `!!
`Second` is ignored...

Comment: @Altair: I have added some code as answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getValue()` method gets `MyResource` element, from there, you need to get all Items under `MyResource` and do `getElementValue()`. Example code is:

```
   public Map getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < n.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(getElementValue(n.item(i)));
        }
        //Here store it in list/map and return list/map instead of String
        return list/MapHere;
    }
```

Comment: where should i put this code. See that my for loop is running.
how should i call this method ?

Comment: @Altair: you have this method in XMLParser class.

Comment: `System.out.println(getElementValue(n.item(i)));` is showing all the items in my Logcat output...but only `First` is retrieved.

Comment: @Altair: my code is example to print to console, if you want it returned, you need to store those values some where right? put them in map (or) list or some where.

Comment: okay.well i am storing it in map na ??
`map.put(KEY_ITEM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM));`

Comment: after adding `ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();` `temp.add(str);` ..i am getting error 
`The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>)` in my ActivityClass.