# Android File I/O openFileInput() undefined

Tags: android, file-io

```
            package com.example.tictactoeshowgrid;

            import android.os.Bundle;
            import java.io.*;
            import android.widget.Toast;
            import android.content.*;

            import java.io.FileInputStream;
            import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.util.Date;

            import android.content.Context;

                public class ImportOBJ {

                protected void onCreate(String filename) {
                    try
                    {
                        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                        String line = null, input="";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            input += line;
                        reader.close();
                        fis.close();
                        //toast("File successfully loaded.");
                        //return input;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //toast("Error loading file: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                        //return "";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am looking at an example of File I/O for Android. I am wondering why openFileInput is coming up with an error as being an undefined function. I was thinking that maybe I missed an import? If not then there must be some other problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did u got the valid file means "xyz.txt" u write onCreate()..i'm sure this is user defined method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for accessing `openFileInput` method in non Activity class you will need to pass Activity Context to it by sending Context using parametrized method or using `ImportOBJ` class constructor as:

```
protected void onCreate(String filename,Context context) {
   try
     {
         FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);  
         //...your code here...      
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
}
```

and from your Activity pass context as:

```
ImportOBJ obj_import=new ImportOBJ();
obj_import.onCreate(<File_Name_Here>,Your_Current_Activity_Name.this);
```

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK man please HELP !!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/how-to-parse-same-name-tag-in-android-xml-dom-parsing

Answer (score 1):

If error is :

> The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type ...

You have to use `openFileInput` in a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).For example an `Activity` is a `Context`.So if you cahnge your class to this,error must be solve:

```
public class ImportOBJ extends Activity{
.
.
.

}
```

You can see [`What is Context in Android?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) for more details on Context.

Comment: What do you mean by use it in a Context. I don't understand the answer yet.

Comment: @user2209542 Please see my answer again.I add some details.

Comment: That is much more clear to me now. I'm not sure I want a full Activity but I see what you mean? I am aiming for a way where I can instantiate ImportOBJ inside an activity and pass a filename and get an array as a result.

Comment: You can pass an instance of context to your method.