# Force close with SharedPreferences and toggle button in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, oncreate, togglebutton

i have a problem with my toggle button and i get always a force close. The code of button:

```
public void getToggle(View view) {
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        if (on) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
            LowBatteryReceiver.class);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(compName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Modalità risparmio attivata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.risparmiostate);
            textView.setText("Modalità risparmio on");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); // value to store
            editor.commit();

        }else{
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
            LowBatteryReceiver.class);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(compName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Modalità risparmio disattivata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.risparmiostate);
            textView.setText("Modalità risparmio off");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false); // value to store
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

and in the `onCrerate`

```
public SharedPreferences preferences;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true
        if (tgpref = true) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
        {
          togglebutton.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            togglebutton.setChecked(false);
        }
```

Any ideas? I tryied everything. Thanks. My logcat doesn't work (i don't know why). Doesn't show me anything.

Comment: post the logcat error otherwise it is not easy to find out mean we can not find anything in dark night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
 preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in `onCreate` of Activity because you are not initializing preferences instance which u have declared as class level field before using it in `getToggle` method

Comment: Doesn't work..Ok i have the logcat..I have a fatal error "Unable to start activity" and then "Caused by NullPointerException....MainActivity onCreate(57)"

Comment: Ok now it works, the problem was that i declared the togglebutton after the check condition. The only one problem now is that the toggle start in "on" state instead "off". Why?

Comment: man please HELP !!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/how-to-parse-same-name-tag-in-android-xml-dom-parsing

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : hmm...did you find any solution to this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/how-to-parse-same-name-tag-in-android-xml-dom-parsing

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
if (tgpref == true)
```

Or

```
if(tgpref)
```

instead Of

> if (tgpref = true).

Try to initialize your  `TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.risparmiostate);` in Oncreate().

Also remove `SharedPreferences` from `SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`As u already declared globally.

Comment: None of this solutions works :(. Is that possible that the problem is the way i set the toggle?

Comment: Put your updated code with xml.If u get logact error then also post it.

Comment: I resolved. the problem was that i declared the togglebutton after the check condition.But now the toggle when i start for the first time the application, is set in "on" state and not "off". How can i set as default state?

Comment: change boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true); to boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);.