# Getting "null" in place of textvalue After parsing XML using PullParser in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-pullparser

I had a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). SO please dont redirect me to that site.

I had already used DOM parser and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421506/how-to-parse-same-name-tag-in-android-xml-dom-parsing) is my problem with that.

I am having the same XML :

```
<MyResource>
<Item>First</Item>
<Item>Second</Item>
</MyResource>
```

And now i have no way but to parse this XML via PullParser.
My methods as taken from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html):

```
private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         List entries = new ArrayList();


            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "MyResource");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                // Starts by looking for the entry tag
                if (name.equals("MyResource")) {
                    entries.add(readEntry(parser));
                } else {
                    skip(parser);
                }
            }  
            return entries;
    }

    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Item readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "Item");
            String text = null;
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("Item")) {
                    text = readMyText(parser);
                } else {
                    skip(parser);
                }
            }
            return new Item(text);
    }

    private String readMyText(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "Item");
        String text = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "Item");
        return text;
    }

    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am getting this as the parsed text :

```
null
null
```

Can anyone help me out of this ??

Comment: post your java code so that we can help you better.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

its taken from here.So i dont think you need my java code as i have given my xml and the code from where i have used.

Comment: @prasharonnet so there yo go...now lets see how fast you can answer...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html) link it is having a good example

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("<foo>Hello World!</foo>"));
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("Start document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("End document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
          System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
          System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
          System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
      }
      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
```

Comment: i have updted my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a sample code to parse your XML. Here u go,

```
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    boolean flag=false;
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("<MyResource><Item>First</Item>    <Item>Second</Item>/MyResource>"));
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              if(xpp.getName().toString().equals("MyResource"){
                 flag=true;
               }
    else if(xpp.getName().toString().equals("Item"){
                 if(flag){
                  String test=xpp.nextText().toString();
//do whatever u want with the data
    }
               }
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              if(xpp.getText().equals("MyResource")
    flag=false;
          } 
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
```